# Load comma seperated values from mysql to dataframe in python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, csv, dataframe

I need to load data which are in a csv like format from a mysql database into a dataframe in python.

The data in the database is structured like this:

```
|-----------|-------------------------------------|
|  part_no  |   property                          |
|-----------|-------------------------------------|
|  1        |   eges,4;volume,532                 |
|  2        |   eges,8;color,red                  |
|  3        |   material,wood;price,45;volume,111 |
|  4        |   color,blue                        |
|-----------|-------------------------------------|
```

The list of properties is not defined in advance. So this needs to be analyzed during runtime. Also order of the properties are not always the same.

What I need at the end is a dataframe of following structure. Undefined values can be either empty or shown as 0.

```
|------------|-------------------------------------------|
|  part_no   | edges | volume | color | material | price |  
|------------|-------------------------------------------|
|   1        |   4   |  532   |       |          |       |
|   2        |   8   |        |  red  |          |       |
|   3        |       |  111   |       |   wood   |  45   |
|   4        |       |        |  blue |          |       |
|------------|-------------------------------------------|
```

Empty values can be shown as 0 or empty.

Can anyone guide me to the right direction how to approach this?

Comment: That's a typo ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read that column from the database into a list (or iterable) of dictionaries.

```
table = #read_from_SQL
records = [dict(cell.split(",") for cell in row)
           for row in table.property.str.split(";")]
# [{'edges': '4', 'volume': '532'},
#  {'color': 'red', 'edges': '8'},
#  {'material': 'wood', 'price': '45', 'volume': '111'},
#  {'color': 'blue'}]
```

Then you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
#   color edges material price volume
# 0   NaN     4      NaN   NaN    532
# 1   red     8      NaN   NaN    NaN
# 2   NaN   NaN     wood    45    111
# 3  blue   NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN
```

Convert the values to `float`, where applicable:

```
df3 = df2.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
#   color  edges material  price  volume
# 0   NaN    4.0      NaN    NaN   532.0
# 1   red    8.0      NaN    NaN     NaN
# 2   NaN    NaN     wood   45.0   111.0
# 3  blue    NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN
```

You still need to add the part number to those dictionaries, though.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks much!